# Can we use Proof Assistants beyond mathematics?

Tags: usage

After receiving responses from [this question](https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/questions/6/what-are-some-examples-of-proof-assistants-doing-something-useful) as a Liberal Artist I'm interesting in other Proof Assistant appliances, beyond Mathematics and Software Verification. I was wondering: how one can use proof assistants in roles that don't imply mathematics directly but only after some level of rigour and subtle observation at necessary scale but different from Math top-level domain.

What I'm looking for could be:

- Philosophy
- Music
- Chemistry
- Physics
- Biology
- Natural Language Processing
- Poetry
- etc...

Comment: I guess only Math, Logic Teacher would fit from this list. Maybe Formal Philosopher or Musician who want to deal with Music at Abstract Algebra level with Groups also could be added. There also is a generalization of proving of Web Development to Verification of Software. Anyway you should consult how to correct the Answer. The simple answer you can't use Proof Assistants without Math.

Comment: Or you can allow me to rewrite you question if you trustMe, seems I got your idea and can evolve the question for mathematicians.

Comment: @NamdakTönpa sure, I don't mind if you re-write :)

Comment: Check this out! Unfortunately I formulated question in a way we miss good answer from Dima.

Comment: Let's see maybe we could save your question! ;-)

Comment: Hint: Proof Assistants applicable to all these areas!

Comment: If you will save this question from deletion I promise to answer!

Comment: @NamdakTönpa I wasn't planning on deletion :

Comment: Then would be possible to put Modal Homotopy Type Theory: The Prospect of a New Logic for Philosophy by David Corfield into this context.

Comment: And even Appendix B. from Favonia's PhD!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

They are used a lot in software development,to verify correctness of implementations, and even to generate executable code (this is called *program extraction*). See https://softwarefoundations.cis.upenn.edu/

Comment: I propose to put this answer into mentioned question "Proof Assistant Appliances" #6, where we already have curated list of Software Verification research.

Comment: You will miss acceptance but I will give you +10! :-)

Comment: done, see https://proofassistants.stackexchange.com/a/414/74 (with few extras added)

Comment: Great, thank you!